# Creating a pixel buffer Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, opengl

I want to create an NSOpenGLPixelBuffer for offscreen rendering. For now, I'm even unable to init it. Here's the code:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[] = {
    NSOpenGLPFAPixelBuffer,
    NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
    NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
    (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute) 0
};

NSOpenGLPixelFormat* format = [[[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attribs] autorelease];
NSOpenGLPixelBuffer* pixBuf = [[NSOpenGLPixelBuffer alloc]
                               initWithTextureTarget: GL_TEXTURE_2D
                               textureInternalFormat: GL_RGBA
                               textureMaxMipMapLevel: 0
                               pixelsWide: 32
                               pixelsHigh: 32];

NSLog(@"pbuf address: %p", pixBuf);
```

I've tried to fiddle with pixel format and width, height but nothing seems to work. I repeatedly get nil for the pixBuf. I'm using Xcode 9 on MacOS 10.13. It says the NSOpenGLPixelBuffer is deprecated but it should still work, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSOpenGLPixelBuffer` has been [deprecated since OS X Lion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenglpixelbuffer), which itself [dates back to 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Lion). No wonder you`re getting `nil`.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html), Apple propose a new approach to drawing into textures:

> Finally note that the entirety of the NSOpenGLPixelBuffer class should be considered deprecated. Use [IOSurface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iosurface) in conjunction with [GL framebuffer objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) as a replacement.

See [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MultiGPUIOSurface/Listings/ServerOpenGLView_m.html) to get a grasp of how it needs to be.

Comment: So it seems that the old api just won't work. I was actually working on a legacy system with the above code. Anyway, thanks for the heads up; I'll look into the example and try to work with that.

Answer (score 2):

Might be help following code. you replace GL_TEXTURE_2D to this GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT.

```
// Create an OpenGL pixel buffer
pixBuf = [[NSOpenGLPixelBuffer alloc] initWithTextureTarget:GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT textureInternalFormat:GL_RGBA textureMaxMipMapLevel:0 pixelsWide:32 pixelsHigh:32];
NULL_ERROR_EXIT(pixBuf, "Unable to create NSOpenGLPixelBuffer");
```